# python memory error, overflowing float?

Tags: python, floating-point

I am doing a homework to compute `e` using the limit when `n` tends to infinity of `(1+1/n)^n`. I know this is a very dumb way to compute it, but I have to.

I am supposed to test my results for a value of up to `n = 10 ^20`.

However my program dies with memory error at `10^7` and I am not really sure why. This is my code:

```
def pow(n):
  p = (1.0 + 1.0/n)
  for _ in range(1,n+1):
    p = p * (1.0 + 1.0/n)
  return p

def e(k):
  print 'e with k =', k, 'is', pow(10**k)


map(e, range(1,21))
```

So my question is what's happening here? Am I overflowing whatever it is that python is using to store my `p` variable? If so, it has to be very big `10^6` is `1344` bits long. How are floats managed by python?

I cant answer my own question yet, so here it is.

The problem was that `range(10**7)` is a list that is too large for python.
Now it works as this:

```
def pow(n):
  p = (1.0 + 1.0/n)
  c = 0
  while (c < n):
    p = p * (1.0 + 1.0/n)
    c += 1
  return p

def e(k):
  print "e with k =", k, 'is', pow(10**k)


map(e, range(1,21))
```

Comment: Your loop is never going to finish with `n=10^20`, even if you swap `range` for `xrange`.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't supposed to use a built-in exponentiation operator to compute `p**n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using Python 2, in which `range` creates a list.  So when you do `range(1,10**20)`, you are trying to create a list that is 10**20 elements long, which is too big for your available memory.

Instead, use `xrange(1, n+1)`.  Then go get some lunch, because it's going to be a while before that loop finishes running.  (Alternatively, change your `pow` function so it does `(1.0+1.0/n)**n` instead of doing the exponentiation manually by repeated multiplication.)

Comment: You are right. For some reason I assumed lazy evaluation. Is there some way to work around it and still use a map (It looks fancy)?

Comment: @user3363133: Actually the map is pretty pointless in this case, since all it does is return a list of `None`.  As I said in my answer and user2357112 said in a comment, you can do it faster by using the actual exponentiation operator `**` instead of doing all those multiplications by hand.

Comment: That's part of the assignment :( They think I don't know how to program.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I thought that you meant the range in the map function not the one in pow.